# React Multiple Fetch Requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making 2 fetch requests. I want to convert the data to JSON and then set it to a variable.

```
async componentDidMount() {

     Promise.all([
        await fetch('/link1'),
        await fetch('/link2'),
    ]).then(links => {
        const response1 =  links[0]
        const response2 = links[1]  

        const res1 = response1.json()
        const res2 = response2.json()            
    })

    const data1 = res1.data
    const data2 = res2.data

    ...
```

I'm not able to set `data1` and `data2` to the responses. I am new to this so I'm not sure how to format it. How do I set `data1` and `data2`?

Comment: You're out of scope which is why it's not working as you think it should. What's the end goal, where do these variables need to be accessed from? The function, the module, globally?

Comment: I just pass these variables to some functions to transform the data. Then it gets passed to d3 further down the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```js
let data = [];

Promise.all([fetch("/link1"), fetch("/link2")])
      .then(responses =>
        responses.forEach(res => res.json().then(body => data.push(body)))
      )
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: This answer is superior to awaiting everything in series in an async function.  It gets all those fetches started as soon as possible.

Comment: Isn't the `.json()` async too?  Shouldn't the `.json()` be inside the Promise.all?

Comment: You're right. I just checked this. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I accepted your answer. However, how can I implement `res.send` into this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate further? What do you mean by `res.send`? If you're referring to an API response parameter, that would be present in your backed API code. However, the above code is part of your frontend, in your React project. I assume this, because the above was posted with a tag of reactjs

Comment: Yes this code is front end, but instead of fetching twice in the front end I'm thinking of doing it in the backend and sending the data to the front end. Is this the right approach in your opinion?

Comment: Depends. Does the backend have access to the source of data or will it also have to make 2 separate fetch requests. If the former, then it makes sense to combine and format the data in your backend and send it to the frontend. If the backend also needs to make 2 requests, then you're just adding another layer of abstraction

Comment: Well the front end fetches from the backend which fetches from an API. So I'm wondering if the backend should make both fetches and then `res.send` to the front end ? I hope that makes sense

Comment: In that case, should just do this from the frontend. You add latency by making the fetch from the back end. Not to mention that you would have to maintain code in 2 places for this particular feature

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to those variables under render, it is common to store them in a state variable.

```
async componentDidMount() {

 Promise.all([
    await fetch('/link1'),
    await fetch('/link2'),
]).then(links => {
    const response1 =  links[0]
    const response2 = links[1]  

    const res1 = response1.json()
    const res2 = response2.json()
    this.setState({data1: res1.data, data2: res2.data})
})
```

Then use you can use `data1` and `data2` as `this.state.data1/2`

To understand why what you are doing is not working, you need to read more about how Promise works. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The main reason is because JS is async, so the data1 and data2 are assigned at the same time as `Promise.all` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do multiple fetches.

```js
Promise.all(
  [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2'
  ].map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()))
).then(results => console.log(results))
```

Promise.all takes an array of promises and returns a new promise that is complete when all the provided promises have completed.

It's best to do the `.json()` work in the thenable chain (since the conversion to JSON is asynchronous as well as the fetch).  And then just await the two final results.

The result of the Promise.all is an array of the results of each promise (in the same order you provided the promises to Promise.all -- doesn't matter which order they completed in.)

Answer (score -2):

Don't use await and Promise both. You can try like this to get the expected output.

```
    async componentDidMount() { 
        const link1Fetch = await fetch('/link1');
        const link2Fetch = await fetch('/link2');
        const data1 = await link1Fetch.json();
        const data2 = await link2Fetch.json();
        console.log(data1, data2);
    }
```

Comment: You do need to use `Promise.all` in order to parallelize the `fetch` requests. This code only performs one fetch at a time.

Comment: Yes I think I do need `Promise.all` but how do I set the data to the variables?